# Perform a Network Analysis in ArcGIS Pro using data from Geofabrik shapefile

Tags: arcgis-pro, openstreetmap, file-geodatabase, network-analyst

I am trying to perform a Network Analysis in ArcGIS Pro for the state of Goiás (Brazil), and want to use as the base map a shapefile from Geofabrik. I have downloaded the shapefile for  "centro-oeste" in Geofabrik ([1]: https://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/brazil.html) and have clipped the data for the states of Goiás and Distrito Federal.

I downloaded the shapefile and then used the "Feature Class To Feature Class" to convert the shapefile, which I've saved in a feature dataset inside a geotadabase.
Wright clicking the feature dataset, in the Catalog Pane, I was able to create a New Network Dataset from the shapefile I have just transformed into a feature class. I then followed the steps in [https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/how-to-create-a-usable-network-dataset.htm][1] to change some parameters in the Properties of my Network Dataset. With the available data imported from Geofabrik I was only able to change the "Directions" tab, selecting "Support directions" and than changing, in the Field Mapping tab, the "Base Name" option to "name" and the "Country/Region Code" to "ref".

Lastly I used the "Build Network" function to generate my network, which ArcGIS Pro allows, and even shows the final network on the map.

The problem is that when I click run, using the closest facility tool from network analysis, after selecting Facilities and Incidentes (I have tried to connect only two arbitrary incidents to one Facility), it shows the following errors:

> No "Facilities" found for "Location 1" in "Incidents".
>
> No "Facilities" found for "Location 2" in "Incidents".
>
> ERROR 030212: Solve did not find a solution.
>
> Failed to execute (Solve).

I have tried to use the "Integrate" function for the shapefile to try to fill any gaps in the network, but it keeps showing the same error.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?